# Showing GPS Values on I2C LCD using Arduino and ESP8266

Tags: esp8266

I am working with Arduino. I'm using 2 Arduino boards along with 2 ESP8266 modules to transfer data from one Arduino to another Arduino. I want to transfer GPS values from system 1 to system 2 using Wi-Fi module ESP8266 along with Arduino UNO. I've written the main codes for server and client end. I'm not able to print anything on LCD if I'm using ESP8266 and selected 'generic ESP8266' boards.

Comment: do the examples of the LCD library work on the Arduino with the LCD?

Comment: you describe three possible areas of failure ... fail to read data from GPS ... fail to transfer data between arduinos ... fail to display data on LCD ....... which of the three is the actual failure? .... if it is one area of failure, then why are you not asking a specific question about it?